# For loop nested in For loop, called function within for loop reverts list back to orginal value, Python

Tags: python, for-loop

In my code I original call a variable lets say n as,

```
n = 5
```

then I run a function that uses the value n. Later on in the code, I want to have n be a list so I then have

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

My problem is when I have the for loop to call the function previously mentioned, my n reverts to only being used as the original value

```
#my code where I am having trouble
for i in range(len(n)):
     print(n[i])
     #reinitializing some stuff
     for i in range(3):
         #reinitializing something else
     print(n[i])
     function(arg, n, arg)
```

The two different print statements will produce different results other then when n[i] = the original n

Answer (score 0):

Python functions are pass by object-reference, not pass by reference, so your `n` outside the function will not be changed by `function()`.
If you want `n` to be a list after `function()` is called, you can return that list in `function()` and set `n` equal to it instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).